# how to use sys.modules.

Tags: python, module, sys

What would this piece of code do and what is the role of `sys.modules` here?:

```
this_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) 
dir_list = (x for x in os.listdir(this_dir) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(this_dir, x)))

for dirpath in dir_list:
    if dirpath not in project_path:
        project_path.append(os.path.join(this_dir, dirpath))
setattr(sys.modules[__name__], '__path__', project_path)
```

Comment: Looks to me like a needlessly convoluted way of saying `__path__ = project_path`.

Comment: Where did you get this piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code adds all sub directories under current directory (from where script is running) to the path so that any modules can be loaded from it's sub-directories.

```
import os,sys
this_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)  #get the current directory of running script
dir_list = (x for x in os.listdir(this_dir) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(this_dir, x)))     #get the list of directories under current directory 
project_path = []
for dirpath in dir_list:   
    if dirpath not in project_path:
        project_path.append(os.path.join(this_dir, dirpath))
setattr(sys.modules[__name__], '__path__', project_path) #add to sys modules so any modules can be imported from thsi directories
```